# Parsing .Net array like string to PHP array

Tags: php, .net, arrays, parsing

A shipping service is providing me with this weird text format response, after some research i found it is very close to a .net array and i am trying to convert to PHP so i can do something useful with it.

My questions:

1. What is this format?
2. Is there any PHP function i could use to parse it?

   ```
   City[0] = "Elghorashi";
   State[0] = "";
   ZipCode[0] = "";
   CCity[0] = "Elghorashi";
   CState[0] = "";
   CZipCode[0] = "";
   City[1] = "Abugibha";
   State[1] = "";
   ZipCode[1] = "";
   CCity[1] = "Abugibha";
   CState[1] = "";
   CZipCode[1] = "";
   ```

Thanks

Comment: PHP variables and arrays have preceding `$` symbol, unless those are constants..

Comment: That looks like a var_dump of a php array. Are you using a var_dump to output that or is that the raw value being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick little snippit I whipped up to convert a string that looks like a PHP array into an actual PHP array. To be clear the `$newArray` variable is where the array is created to.

```
$string = 'City[0] = "Elghorashi"; State[0] = ""; ZipCode[0] = ""; CCity[0] = "Elghorashi"; CState[0] = ""; CZipCode[0] = ""; City[1] = "Abugibha"; State[1] = ""; ZipCode[1] = ""; CCity[1] = "Abugibha"; CState[1] = ""; CZipCode[1] = "";';
$string = substr($string, 0, -1);

$arr = explode('; ', $string);
$newArray = [];
foreach($arr AS $value){
    $keyVals = explode(' = ', $value);
    preg_match_all('/^(.*?)\[([0-9]+)\]$/', $keyVals[0], $matches);
    $value = is_string($keyVals[1]) ? substr($keyVals[1], 1, -1) : $keyVals[1];
    $newArray[$matches[2][0]][$matches[1][0]] = $value;
}
```